# Create wrapper to hide implementation details for data structures

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have some integrations (like Salesforce) that I would like to hide behind a product-agnostic wrapper (like a CrmService class instead of SalesforceService class).

It seems simple enough that I can just create a CrmService class and use the SalesforceService class as an implementation detail in the CrmService, however, there is one problem. The SalesforceService uses some exceptions and enums. It would be weird if my CrmService threw SalesforceExceptions or you were required to use Salesforce enums.

Any ideas how I can accomplish what I want cleanly?

EDIT: Currently for exceptions, I am catching the Salesforce one and throwing my own custom one. I'm not sure what I should do for the enums though. I guess I could map the Salesforce enums to my own provider-agnostic ones, but I'm looking for a general solution that might be cleaner than having to do this mapping. If that is my *only* option (to map them), then that is okay, just trying to get ideas.

Comment: Can't you just catch the SalesForceExceptions and throw your own custom exceptions?

Comment: @Nick yup, any ideas about the enums though?

EDIT: btw, ill edit my question to say that is what im currently doing for the exceptions. i was hoping there might be a better way of architecting this in general.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any suggestions other than mapping the enums. Not the prettiest, no, but it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you are on the right track, have a read through the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

> The fundamental notion is that **a given object should assume as
>   little as possible about the structure or properties of anything else
>   (including its subcomponents)**, in accordance with the principle of
>   "information hiding".
>
> The advantage of following the Law of Demeter is that **the resulting
>   software tends to be more maintainable and adaptable**. Since objects
>   are less dependent on the internal structure of other objects, object
>   containers can be changed without reworking their callers.
>
> Although it **may also result in having to write many wrapper
>   methods** to propagate calls to components; in some cases, this can
>   add noticeable time and space overhead.

So you see you are following quite a good practise which I do generally follow myself, but it does take some effort.

And yes you will have to catch and throw your own exceptions and map enums, requests and responses, its a lot of upfront effort but if you ever have to change out Salesforce in a few years you will be regarded a hero.

As with all things software development, you need to way up the effort versus the benefit you will gain, if you think you are likely never to change out salesforce? then is it really needed? ... for you to decide.

Comment: i agree with your advice

Answer (score 1):

To make use of good **OOP** practices, I would create a small **interface** `ICrm` with the basic members that all your CRM's have in common. This interface will include the typical methods like `MakePayment()`, `GetPayments()`, `CheckOrder()`, etc. Also create the Enums that you need like `OrderStatus` or `ErrorType`, for example.

Then create and implement your specific classes implementing the interface, e.g. `class CrmSalesForce : ICrm`. Here you can convert the specific details to this particular CRM (SalesForce in that case) to your common ICrm. Enums can be converted to string and the other way around if you have to (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxydatf9(v=vs.110).aspx).

Then, as a last step, create your `CrmService` class and use in it **Dependency Injection** (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921152.aspx), that's it, pass a type of `ICrm` as a parameter in its constructor (or methods if you prefer to) . That way you keep your CrmService class quite cohesive and independent, so you create and use different Crm's without the need to change most of your code.

Comment: i am using this pattern elsewhere, but in the case of how our application has already been setup, it wont fit as well here. thank you for the advice though!